# Positioning multiple SVG elements in div HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, position

I have 2 charts which looks like this:

[image]

I need to display the tag-cloud next to the bar-chart. I am using D3 to display these charts and my HTML division looks like this (`svg1` displays bar-chart and `svg2` displays tag-cloud):

[image]

I would appreciate any help. Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aj3g5tqg/14/). In the demonstration I want circle to appear next to the bar chart.

Thanks!

Comment: can you be clearer about the question?

Comment: @FabioCosta I have added demonstration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just float the elements like here on [your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aj3g5tqg/16/)

```
d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id","area1")
    .style("width", 500)
    .style("float","left");
```

And

```
function wordCloud(){
    var wC = {};

    d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .style("float","left")
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50).append("circle").attr("cx", 25).attr("cy", 25).attr("r", 25).style("fill", "purple");
    return wC;
}
```